# Can't add custom element in Text mode in TinyMCE editor in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would like to add a custom element in the TinyMCE editor in WordPress.

In the **Visual** mode it should look like this: [image]

In the **Text** mode it should be: `<!-- example -->`

The element is inserted to the page content like this:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('insertElement', false)   # 'insertElement' is defined below
```

When this code is run in the **Visual** mode, the image is inserted properly.

However, running this code in the **Text** mode results in nothing (`<!-- example -->` doesn't appear).

Why is that?

---

Here is the TinyMCE code itself: (CoffeeScript)

```
(($) ->
  tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('example')

  tinymce.create 'tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin',
    init: (ed, url) ->
      elementHTML = '<img class="example" src="http://goo.gl/eejO0" />'

      ed.addCommand 'insertElement', ->
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, elementHTML)

      ed.onPostProcess.add (ed, o) ->
        if o.get
          $wrapper = $('<div />').html(o.content)

          $('.example', $wrapper).each ->
            $(this).replaceWith("<!-- example -->")

          o.content = $wrapper.html()

      ed.onBeforeSetContent.add (ed, o) ->
        if o.content
          o.content = o.content.replace(/<!-- example -->/g, elementHTML)
    ,
    getInfo: ->
      longname: 'Example Plugin'
      author: 'Me'
      authorurl: 'http://mysite.com'
      infourl: 'http://mysite.com'
      version: '1.0'

  tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', tinymce.plugins.ExamplePlugin)
) jQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in the textmode there is no real tinymce editor present, but just a normal textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you looking for but, this is my solution.

```
<h1><img alt="" src="http://static.tinymce.com/tinymce/js/4.0b2/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-yell.gif" /></h1>
&nbsp;
<h1><img alt="" src="http://static.tinymce.com/tinymce/js/4.0b2/plugins/emoticons/img/smiley-smile.gif" data-mce-selected="1" /></h1>
```

Hope it's ok!